# Phonebook in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a test console program-phonebook with Python. My IDE is JetBrains PyCharm. I have 5 functions - Search contact, Enter contact, Delete contact, All phones and Exit. My question is how can I make the program to save information in text file and when I compile it, the information will be saved in this text file ?

Comment: Is this homework? And where is your code?

Comment: I would google something like "file input/output in python tutorial"

Comment: Yes, something like that

Answer (score 0):

You could write the data to a csv file. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

This should help : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

I think for your case the easiest would be to write data to a ***python file*** as follows:

```
with open('PathToAFile/MyFile.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write('contact_names =[' + contact_name1 + ',' + contact_name2... + ']\n')
```

This will make it extremely easy to load data later without having to parse (as in a csv).

In the example code i provide, im saving your contact names to a list called 'contact_names' in a python file named 'MyFile.py'. When you execute 'MyFile.py
 you will have access to the 'contact_names' variable